# Define Parameter list in React Native Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-typescript

I've a Sections screen that gets quiz data from database and passes it off to Quiz screen based on the Section.
The structure of the data from database is:

```
{
  sections: [
   {
    questions: [
     {
      question: "",
      options: ["", "", ""],
      answer: "",

...

}
```

Since I'm using React Navigation with TypeScript I need to define the `RootStackParamList` for Section and Quiz screen, something like:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Modules: undefined;
  Sections: {data: {}};
  Quiz: {data: {}};
};
```

Navigating across screens like:

```
{data.sections.slice(1).map((section, index) => (
 <TouchableOpacity
  key={index}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Quiz', {data: section.questions})}
 </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

I get the following error message on the line when navigating to the new screen with params `onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Quiz', {data: section.questions})}`:

```
Argument of type '{ data: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ sections: [{ questions: []; }]; }'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'data' does not exist in type '{ sections: [{ questions: []; }]; }'.ts(2345)
```

How can I define `RootStackParamList` in order to fix the error?

ModuleList.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  StyleSheet,
  useColorScheme,
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {List} from 'react-native-paper';
import {db} from '../../firebase';
import {ref, onValue} from 'firebase/database';
// import { AdmobContext } from "../components/AdmobController";
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';

type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Modules: undefined;
  Sections: {data: {}};
  Quiz: undefined;
};
type ModuleListScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Modules'
>;
type Props = {
  navigation: ModuleListScreenNavigationProp;
};

const ModuleList = ({navigation}: Props) => {
  const [quiz, setQuiz] = useState({});
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
    optionBackgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#333333' : '#D3D3D3',
  };
  // let { renderBanner } = useContext(AdmobContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    return onValue(ref(db, '/'), (querySnapShot: {val: () => {}}) => {
      const data = querySnapShot.val() || {};
      let quizItems = {...data};
      setQuiz(quizItems);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor}]}>
      <SafeAreaView>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Sections', {data: quiz})}
          style={[
            styles.listItem,
            {backgroundColor: style.optionBackgroundColor},
          ]}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {color: style.color}]}>
            Security Guard Training
          </Text>
          <List.Icon color={style.color} icon="security" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Sections', {data: quiz})}
          style={[
            styles.listItem,
            {backgroundColor: style.optionBackgroundColor},
          ]}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {color: style.color}]}>Useful Links</Text>
          <List.Icon color={style.color} icon="link" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  listItem: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
});

export default ModuleList;
```

SectionList.tsx

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  useColorScheme,
} from 'react-native';
import {List} from 'react-native-paper';
// import { AdmobContext } from "../components/AdmobController";
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {RouteProp} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';

type QuestionDataType = {
  question: string;
  options: string[];
  answer: string;
};
type SectionDataType = {
  sections: {
    questions: QuestionDataType[];
  }[];
};
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Modules: undefined;
  Sections: {data: QuestionDataType[]};
  Quiz: {data: QuestionDataType[]};
};
type SectionListScreenNavigationProp = StackNavigationProp<
  RootStackParamList,
  'Sections'
>;
type SectionListScreenRouteProp = RouteProp<RootStackParamList, 'Sections'>;
type Props = {
  navigation: SectionListScreenNavigationProp;
  route: SectionListScreenRouteProp;
};

const SectionList = ({navigation, route}: Props) => {
  const data = route.params.data;
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const style = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
    color: isDarkMode ? Colors.lighter : Colors.darker,
    optionBackgroundColor: isDarkMode ? '#333333' : '#D3D3D3',
  };
  // let { renderBanner } = useContext(AdmobContext);

  return (
    <ScrollView
      style={[styles.container, {backgroundColor: style.backgroundColor}]}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        key={1}
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Quiz', {data: data.sections[0].questions})
        }
        style={[
          styles.listItem,
          {backgroundColor: style.optionBackgroundColor},
        ]}>
        <Text style={[styles.text, {color: style.color}]}>Section 1</Text>
        <List.Icon color={style.color} icon="frequently-asked-questions" />
      </TouchableOpacity>

      {data.sections.slice(1).map((section, index) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          key={index}
          onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Quiz', {data: section.questions})}
          style={[
            styles.listItem,
            {backgroundColor: style.optionBackgroundColor},
          ]}>
          <Text style={[styles.text, {color: style.color}]}>
            {'Section '}
            {index + 2}
          </Text>
          <List.Icon color={style.color} icon="frequently-asked-questions" />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ))}
    </ScrollView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingVertical: 30,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    position: 'relative',
  },
  listItem: {
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
    marginBottom: 1,
    paddingHorizontal: 10,
    paddingVertical: 15,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 18,
    marginHorizontal: 15,
  },
});

export default SectionList;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first define types for your section and question like this:

```
type QuestionDataType = {
  question: string,
  options: string[],
  answer: string,
}
type SectionDataType = {
 sections: {
   questions: QuestionDataType[];
 }[];
}
```

Then inside the **RootStackParamList** type:

```
type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Modules: undefined;
  Sections: {data: QuestionDataType[]};
  Quiz: {data: {}};
};
```

And please remember when you get data from the server (your database), for the variable/state that store the response define **SectionDataType** till everything be ok when use that for passing the data in the navigate.
At the end your navigation section will execute without error:

```
{data.sections.slice(1).map((section, index) => (
 <TouchableOpacity
  key={index}
  onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Quiz', {data: section.questions})}
 </TouchableOpacity>
))}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think you meant to use SectionDataType for Sections in RootStackParamList. I see a different error now:
`Property 'sections' does not exist on type 'SectionDataType[]'`. Any ideas or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You're welcome, actually you should define **QuestionDataType[]** instead of **SectionDataType[]** inside RootStackParamList Sections type because you're navigate with array of questions so, try this ```Sections: {data: QuestionDataType[]};```, and if you still have problem, please update your question with new code and notice me.

Comment: Got it, I used the QuestionDataType[] now and the error changes to `Property 'sections' does not exist on type 'QuestionDataType[]'.` This error is thrown on the line -
`{data.sections.slice(1).map((section, index) => (`

Comment: I assume you have a state as data, check out your data state definition be like this ```const [data, setData] = useState<SectionDataType>();``` after fetch update data state with **setData**,  so I guess you didn't pass ```SectionDataType``` to the data in the definition and when you want to map the data, throw missing **sections**. And if the data for first time is undefined use ```?.``` instead of ```.``` when map data, like: ```data?.sections.slice(1)...```.

Comment: I see, I'm actually just passing data in route params and accessing it using `route.params.data`. I added the whole `SectionList` and `ModuleList` files to my question. Hopefully that is useful. Should I redefine the data in `SectionList` somehow?

Comment: I suggest you check out SectionList structure in RN docs, you'll have two approach to achieve the thing you want, first you are able to before navigate to Quiz screen prepare data structure then pass it or inside the quiz screen define new state, inside a useEffect map the paramed data then show that inside SectionList.

Answer (score 0):

I have a handy-dandy way to declare my React-Navigation thigs.

Inside your `AppNavigator.tsx`

```
// Telling TypeScript what to expect as "route" identifier
export interface AppRoutes {
  home: "home";
  settings: "settings";
}

// Telling TypeScript what every screen will expect as ParamTypes
//  - home screen will ask for 'HomeProps', but it's optional
//  - settings screen will ask for 'SettingsProps', required!
export type AppNavigationScreenProps = {
  home?: HomeProps;
  settings: SettingsProps;
}

// Black magic
export type AppStackParamList = {
  [key in keyof AppRoutes]: AppNavigationScreenProps[key];
};

// Stack navigator for this route that uses black magic
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator<AppStackParamList>();


// Interface for my component (empty, but one does not know when he will need it)
interface AppNavigatorProps {}

// Navigator component, home of all navigation
const AppNavigator: React.FC<AppNavigatorProps> = (_: AppNavigatorProps) => {
    // ... things
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="home" // This will be restricted to "home" and "settings"
                    component={Home}  // Only "Home" component can fit here, see Home.tsx
                    options={/* Things */}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name="settings" // This will be restricted to "home" and "settings"
                    component={Settings} // Only "Settings" component can fit here, see Settings.tsx
                    options={/* Things */}
                />
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
```

And then inside your `Home.tsx` and `Settings.tsx` component:

```
// ---------------------------------------
// Home.tsx
// ---------------------------------------

// This is the interface that AppNavigation.tsx was referencing!
export interface HomeProps {
    myData: string[]
    myOptionalData?: number;
    // ...and so on
}

// Black Magic 2.0 that will make "Home" fit as "home" reference
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<AppNavigationScreenProps, "home">;

// Home component!
const Home: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }: Props) => {
    // Can be undefined, since HomeProps is optional!
    const params = route.params; 
    const myData = params?.myData;

    // ....things and black magic
}

// ---------------------------------------
// Settings.tsx
// ---------------------------------------

// This is the interface that AppNavigation.tsx was referencing!
export interface SettingsProps {
    name: string;
    myOtherData: MyDataType;
}

// Black Magic 2.0 that will make "Settings" fit as "settings" reference
type Props = NativeStackScreenProps<AppNavigationScreenProps, "settings">;

// Setting component!
const Settings: React.FC<Props> = ({ navigation, route }: Props) => {
    // It's not optional can use it directly!
    const { name, myOtherData } = route.params; 

    // ....things and black magic
}
```

Hope it will help to make sure your data will be typed correctly for every screen you will make.

Make sure your data is serializable (you should not pass functions as arguments), if not you will receive some warnings about screen-to-screen communication.